# How to see the instructions inside of compiled language executable files?

Tags: c, executable

When i compile a C/C++ source file the compiler generates another executable file. How to see the instructions of that file? What is the process known as?

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
./hello
```

Here, the first after executing the first line a file name 'hello' gets generated. I need to see the instructions of this 'hello' file.

Comment: Disassembly? Decompilation? Reverse engineering? Staring at undecipherable wall of hex?

Comment: Suppose, i have a file named hello.c, after compiling this file i get a.out, now i want to see what is in a.out file

Comment: Open it in any editor and you will see its contents. Though I'm guessing that's not what you want. So what exact format and information do you want to get out of the file? The original source code? The assembly instruction? The ELF sections? The raw binary values? etc.

Comment: If i execute this file i get some output. So, there must be some instructions in 'a.out' file which lead my machine to show me the output. I need to see those instructions.

Comment: Then it sounds like you want to disassemble the code. On Linux you can do: `objdump -d a.out`. Read the `objdump` manual for more options to control exactly what output is dumped.

Comment: @Toddler so that would be the last option: "staring at undecipherable wall of hex"

Comment: You are aware of the difference of script languages like python or perl and compiled languages like C or C++, aren't you? You are aware of the necessary step to compile (and link) C code into an executable, because you mention it. The script languages (which have some readabe instructions in their "exdcutable") use a separate executable (the interpreter). Could you maybe [edit] your question to clarify what you want to see and use these terms and expressions?

Answer (score 8):

The executable a.out file is in binary format.
You can open that in any text editor(Ex: vi, vim etc) or hex editor but you won't be able to understand the contents.

You can use some commands to get more information about what is contained in the executable file.
Some example commands are: nm, strings, objdump

Example:

```
$ nm a.out
$ strings a.out
$ objdump -xD --demangle a.out
```

Read their manual to know more about them